# Prove by contraposition help.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm not very familiar with contraposition and so I am having some difficulties proving the statement.

> If $n$ is a positive integer such that $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ or $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $n$ is not a perfect square.

What would be a good way to prove this?
Need help please.

Comment: The contrapositive:  If n is a perfect square, then $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$ or $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$

Comment: When you have a logical statement of the form "if $P$ then $Q$", the contraposition is the statement "if not $Q$, then not $P$". It is logically equivalent to the first statement, and often lends itself easier to prove. In this case, the statement "$n$ is a positive integer that is $2 \mod 4$ or $3 \mod 4$" is $P$, since it follows the "if", and the statement "$n$ is not a perfect square" is $Q$, the implication. We can form the contraposition by negating $P$ and $Q$ and putting them in the right order.

Comment: so then it is said as "if $n$ is a perfect square, then $n$ is not a positive integer such that....."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the contrapositive of a conditional:

'If P then Q'

is the statement:

'If not Q then not P'

Applied to your statement, we would thus get:

'If $n$ is a perfect square, then $n$ is not a positive integer such that $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ or $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$'

... But somehow I doubt that's what they meant. In fact, the original statement was probably meant as:

'For any positive integer $n$, it holds that if $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ or $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $n$ is not a perfect square'

So then by taking the contrapositive of the contrapositive of the conditional that is part of that general statement about positive integers, we get:

'For any positive integer $n$, it holds that if $n$ is a perfect square, then it is not the case that $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ or $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$'

...which makes a lot more sense.

Indeed, to prove this statement:

Take $n$ to be a positive integer and assume it is a perfect square. So, $n=k^2$ with $k$ an integer. $k$ is either even or odd. If $k$ is even, then $k=2m$ for some integer $m$, and so $n=(2m)^2=4m^2$. Hence, $n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$. If $k$ is odd, then $k=2k+1$ for some integer $m$' and so $n=(2m+1)^2=4m^2+4m+1$, and hence $n \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. So, it is not the case that $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ or that $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: ok, I slighlty understand how the contrapositive works, but how would you use this to prove the proposition?

Comment: @Unkown96 n is k^2 where k is either even or odd. So, either k = 2m or k = 2m+1. So n is either 4k^2 (hence n mod 4 = 0) or n is 4k^2 + 4k +1 (hence n mod 4 = 1)

Answer (score 0):

To prove $A\implies B$ by contrapositive you need to prove $\bar B \implies \bar A$. Let's prove that if $n$ is a perfect square then $n \equiv 2 [ 4]$ or $n \equiv 3 [4]$ is not true.

Suppose $n$ is a perfect square, say $n=k^2, k\in \mathbb Z$ and suppose $k \equiv 3[4]$ then $n=k^2 \equiv 3 [4]$ which means $\exists q \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n=k^2=(4q+3)^2=16q^2+24q+9=4(4q^2+6q+2)+1\equiv 1[4]$ which is a contradiction. A similar argument shows $k\equiv 2[4]$ is also not possible. So we are left with $k\equiv 0[4]\implies n \equiv 0[4]$ or $k \equiv 1[4]\implies n \equiv 1[4]$ which implies $k$ is not equal to 3 or 2 modulo 4.